# Is it possible to underline text on JTextField?If Yes, How?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextfield, underline

can anyone please tell me how to underline text on `JTextField`? I create a code that have a `JPopupMenu` when you right clicked on textfield the menu "bold,italic,underline,plain" will popup and when you clicked underline it will underline the text inside `JtextField`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - by adjusting the `Font` attributes of the component

```
Font font = textField.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
textField.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Comment: cannot find symbol...what do i need to import?

Comment: If you're using an IDE, you can use auto-import, e.g `Ctrl+Shift+O` for Eclipse

Comment: Then look it up in the javadoc, or use an IDE

Comment: TextAttribute cannot find symbol

Comment: First result from Google [`java.awt.font.TextAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html)